# include inside nestedscrollview inside constraintlayout with maxheight causes include with variable height to not be expanded in its full height

Tags: android-xml, android-constraintlayout, android-nestedscrollview, android-include

Following snippet from my layout xml:

```
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_home_info_card_car_position"
            android:maxHeight="300dp"
            >

                <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView        
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:elevation="10dp">

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/fragment_home_filter_chips"
                        layout="@layout/selection_chips"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp" />

                </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

wraps the content correctly, it wraps the `include` and doesn't exceed the height. But the content of the `include` get cut off approx 100dp down when scrolling. This may be because there is a rather slow fill of the include (in the background with a `lifeCyclescope` coroutine).

In my effort to overcome this I just constraint the height to a fixed value like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fragment_home_info_card_car_position"
            
            >
...
```

Now suddenly the height of the include was correctly justified, and I could scroll down the bottom of it, but of course not constrained to the content if it was smaller than 300dp...

My question is, how do I constraint the height as in the first snippet and is sure that my include is fully expanded (viewed expanded inside the scrollview) ?

Do `maxHeight` do some "magic" that isn't quite well here ?

Comment: This is probably not the issue that you are having, but replace `match_parent` with `0dp` and the appropriate constraints. From the documentation: _"Important: MATCH_PARENT is not recommended for widgets contained in a ConstraintLayout. Similar behavior can be defined by using MATCH_CONSTRAINT with the corresponding left/right or top/bottom constraints being set to "parent"."_

Comment: Wonder why lint doesn't flag that actually... ...of course... but it is quite convenient just to say "match_parent".

Comment: Should be a lint check but, alas, there is not. An earlier version of the text I quoted said that "unpredictable" things may happen if `match_parent` is used. That text has been removed, so it is possible that `match_parent` works OK but it is not guaranteed.

Comment: I tried as you said to change to `            
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:elevation="10dp">` 
But this time it disappeared...

Comment: I'll see if I manage to share a "proof-of-concept" on this... I'll do a "static" workaround until solved.